# unable to proxy from nginx to kibana

Tags: nginx, logstash, kibana

I am trying to proxy requests from nginx to kibana (logstash).  I can access the kibana dashboard on port 9292 - I can confirm that a service is listening on port 9292.  I can successfully proxy from nginx to other services but the proxy directive for kibana (port 9292) does not work - I can proxy to 9200 for elasticsearch.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this further would be appreciated.

**Update:** 
I have tried changing the server setup in upstream to point to 0.0.0.0 as well as the server address but neither option works.  The request gets routed to the default server.

**Another Update:**
I have noticed that removing the proxy parameters from the nginx default file allows me to forward the request to the kibana listneing port - however, kibana complains about missing "dashboards/default.json" which I am guessing is due to some missing or misconfigured setup in nginx.

**default (/etc/nginx/sites-available)**

```
upstream logstash {
        server 127.0.0.1:9292;  ##kibana
        keepalive 100;
}

server {
        listen 84;
        listen [::]:84 ipv6only=on;
        root /var/www/;
        index index.html index.htm;
        server_name logstash;

        ##logging per server
        access_log /var/log/nginx/logstash/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/logstash/error.log;

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_pass http://logstash;
        }
}
```

Comment: first of all you should check direct access, for example try to open with browser http://127.0.0.1:9292/ (if you use local machine), or curl -v http://127.0.0.1:9292/

Comment: direct access works - but not the proxy setup.

Comment: I see two possible issues. First: it looks like some requests need to go to 9292 (for Kibana) and others need to go to 9200 (for ES), but you're just sending all of them to 9292. Second: I haven't used the embedded Kibana setup, but I know that a standalone setup required a change in `config.js` to direct AJAX requests to a port other than 9200, where your proxy only seems to be listening on 84. I have more experience with Apache, but [this example setup](https://github.com/elasticsearch/kibana/blob/master/sample/nginx.conf) might be handy reference.

Comment: thanks for sharing - I can hit 9200 and 9292 directly (kibana UI shows up on 9292)-  I am using the embedded version and I cannot find any config.js-  I will go through the logstash jar today and check if I need to change the config file (I'm assuming its part of the jar file).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem seems to be

```
proxy_pass http://your-logstash-host;
```

If you look at the logs in your LogStash Web, you'll see "WARN -- : attack prevented by Rack::Protection::JsonCsrf"

There's some built-in security, which I'm not familiar with, provided by rack-protection to prevent Cross-origin resource sharing attacks. The problem is that the proxy_pass from Nginx looks like a CORS attack to ruby rack protection.

EDIT:

As previously stated, the module Rack::Protection::CSRF is the one throwing this warning.

I have opened the code and we can clearly see what's going on:

```
def has_vector?(request, headers)
  return false if request.xhr?
  return false unless headers['Content-Type'].to_s.split(';', 2).first =~ /^\s*application\/json\s*$/
  origin(request.env).nil? and referrer(request.env) != request.host
end
```

So here's the required nginx config required to pass the requests so that Sinatra will accept them:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  logstash.frontend.domain.org;

    location / {
        # Proxying all requests from logstash.frontend to logstash.backend
        proxy_pass   http://logstash.backend.domain.org:9292;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        # Set Referer and Host to prevent CSRF panick by Sinatra
        proxy_set_header Referer my-host-04;
        proxy_set_header Host my-host-04.domain.org;

        # Alternatively to setting the Referer and Host, you could set X-Requested-With
        #proxy_set_header X-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes I saw that earlier as well but dropped looking into the issue after some time.  I will update SO once I resolve the issue.